How can I calculate Kubernetes Availability?
Background
I am part of an internal team that provides Kubernetes as a platform. I am trying to come up with a way to determine if Kubernetes is Available. Eventually I want this to bubble up into a single SLO.
What I am stuck with
Given that there are so many components in Kubernetes, I am not sure how to come up with the right combination of metrics that could meaningfully indicate that Kubernetes is "Available".
